# How can we get the original order of sql query incovation in a deadlock graph?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

Is the left to right sequence in a sql deadlock graph always based on the order of the sql query encountered in the code?

If not, then how can we find this order? For example query 1 came in and then query 2 came in which resulted in deadlock. I want a way to get this order.

Comment: I don't know if left-to-right is arranged in chronological order of query start time, no, and unfortunately deadlocks don't always include information about the query that actually took the locks that caused the deadlock. You can observe the order by watching the animated replay of the deadlock (.xdl file) using [the free Plan Explorer tool](https://www.sentryone.com/plan-explorer), and there are other things the tool can do to give better guidance around a deadlock than trying to interpret XML manually or staring at 2 circles. *Disclaimer: I used to be the Product Manager for Plan Explorer.*

Comment: What is it that the tool sees in the xdl/xml that it is able to tell the order? Doing a mouse over on on how's circle shows me the sql query for each circle.

Comment: It can't see anything differently, it just tries harder at visualizing the information that is there. See [this blog post](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/new-deadlock-visualizations-in-sql-sentry-and-plan-explorer) for an example.

Comment: I am looking for that specific information so that I am able to decipher the order looking at the xml/xdl.

Comment: Why? SQL Server chooses the victim based on factors that do not include which query started first. And as multiple people have told you, there is nothing purely deterministic about which circle is on the left, or any ties to query start time.

Comment: What do your recommend is the best way to capture this information? Probably deadlock chain?

Comment: IMHO Extended Events, they are already in the `system_health` session that is running by default, see [this post](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/06/capturing-deadlock-information/) and [this post](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6430/monitor-deadlocks-in-sql-server-with-systemhealth-extended-events/).

Comment: Deadlock graph is - but I couldn't find the deadlock chain there. So maybe I need to configure a new session to capture this. Note that the deadlock graph doesn't show which query is blocking. It only shows the current query in the buffer.

Comment: Did you search for something like "monitoring deadlock chain sql server"? First hit: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5658/capturing-sql-server-deadlocks-using-extended-events/

Comment: Yes exactly what I have mentioned. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No.  It's not documented whether there's any consistent ordering to the nodes in a deadlock graph, but it's definitely not based on "the order of the sql query encountered in the code" as that doesn't have a clear and definite meaning.

By definition each session acquired a lock and was not blocked, and those initial locks can happen concurrently or in any order.  And there's no global sequencing of locks, as they can truly happen concurrently on separate schedulers.

Comment: 1) How can I find query order because it is deterministic behaviour as 1 sql will fire and then the next that will cause the deadlock. 2) And do you know if the sql query that I see when hover over the circle the actual sql query?

Comment: 1) They could start at the same time, or one could start first, but become blocked second.  2) It's not.  It's the current query for the session, which may or may not be the one that acquired the lock blocking the other session.